# How to use Avahi as if it were Bonjour

Tags: bonjour, mdns, avahi

I am using Avahi and Bonjour as mDNS responder.

In Bonjour, I am getting answers to my query-in-answer section and additional information such as SRV, A, and AAAA records are in the additional section of the DNS packet.

But in Avahi, all PTR, SRV, A, AAAA are coming in the answer section.

How do I configure Avahi to generate responses the same way as Bonjour?

I'm also looking to make the same query in Avahi, with latency <= 2 msec.

Comment: How are you publishing your services on Avahi ? If your bug is real, then i can think of workarounds if you use the Avahi API in your code. Anyway, Avahi is unmaintained.